# Is it okay to use export frequently to one file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, export

What is the difference between these two export methods?

first method :

```
export const a = 'a';
export const b = 'b';
export const c = 'c';
export const d = 'd';
```

second method :

```
const a = 'a';
const b = 'b';
const c = 'c';
const d = 'd';

export {a,b,c,d};
```

Is there a performance issue if i use too many exports like in the first method?

Or I'm wondering if I don't have to worry about performance issues with too many exports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iam not aware of any performance issues involving having too many exports from one file nor using `{ a,b,c,d }` over `export a; export b; ...`, however it is recommended to only have files export one thing or at most things that are somehow connected/related.

Answer (score 0):

**Named Export**

Named exports are useful to export several values at ones. During the import, it is important to use the same name.

```
    // exporting everyting at ones
    export { Sum, object, array, string, number, boolean, Null };

    // exporting with different names
    export { Sum as adding, number as binary }
```

**Default export**

Default exports are useful to export only a single values. During the import, able to ommit the curly bares and use any name.

```
export default func;

export default function func() {
    return "this a default export.";
}
```